# Speech Recognition Voice Analytics Returns Null (Swift iOS 13)

Tags: swift, speech-recognition, ios13

I'm using iOS 13's speech recognition, and it's not returning the correct Speaking Rate, Average Pause Duration, or Voice Analytics.

Spoken words are correctly printed out, however this is what I get printing out  segment info:

> segment: , substringRange={0, 2},
>   timestamp=0, duration=0, confidence=0, substring=So,
>   alternativeSubstrings=( ), phoneSequence=, ipaPhoneSequence=,
>   voiceAnalytics=(null)

Thanks for your help!

```
func startSpeechRecognition() throws{

    if let recognitionTask = recognitionTask {
        recognitionTask.cancel()
        self.recognitionTask = nil
    }

    try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)
    try audioSession.setActive(true, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)

    recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
    let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode

    if speechRecognizer.supportsOnDeviceRecognition {
        print("support on device recognition")
        recognitionRequest?.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = true
    }

    guard let recognitionRequest = recognitionRequest else {
        fatalError("Unable to created a SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest object")
    }

    recognitionTask = speechRecognizer.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest) { result, error in

        if let result = result {
            let bestString = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
            self.spokenWords = bestString
            if self.spokenWords != nil{
                self.numberOfWordsRecorded = self.spokenWords!.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines).count
                print(bestString)
            }

            for segment in result.bestTranscription.segments {
                print("segment: \(segment)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you remember to include the permissions in the Info.plist? Also, maybe look at [this example](https://www.iowncode.com/ios-sfspeechrecognizer-on-device-recognition/) and see if that works for you.

Comment: Yes, all permissions are included. Otherwise it wouldn't work at all.

Comment: So did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

What ended up working was changing the SFSpeechRecognizer locale from

```
var speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "en_US"))!
```

to

```
var speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US"))!
```